# Sequences $\{\max(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\min(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

If $\{\max(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\min(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge, do $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and  $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge?

An observation: the converse is true.
My attempt to solve question: It is obvious that $\min(a_n,b_n) \leq a_n \leq \max(a_n,b_n)$
and
$\min(a_n,b_n) \leq b_n \leq \max(a_n,b_n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so if $\{\max(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\min(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to the same limit, so do $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and  $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. I suspect this doesn't hold when $\{\max(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\min(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to different limits, but I cannot provide a counterexample.

Comment: Counterexample: $$a_n = (-1)^n \ \ \ \ \ b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\max(a,b)&=\frac12\Bigl(a+b+|a-b|\Bigr),\qquad(1)\\[.4em]
\min(a,b)&=\frac12\Bigl(a+b-|a-b|\Bigr).\qquad(2)
\end{aligned}$$
From $(1)+(2)$, you get $(1'):$ $(a_n+b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges and from $(1)-(2)$, you get $(2'):$ $(|a_n-b_n|)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges. So, if a counterexample exists, it must be so that $(|a_n-b_n|)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not eventually equal to $(a_n-b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ (otherwise $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ would converge by considering $(1')\pm(2')$). Hence the oscillation in @Crostul's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and define$$a_n=\begin{cases}\alpha&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\\beta&\text{ if $n$ is even}\end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\begin{cases}\beta&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\\alpha&\text{ if $n$ is even.}\end{cases}$$Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{a_n,b_n\}=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\min\{a_n,b_n\}=\min\{\alpha,\beta\}.$$But, unless $\alpha=\beta$, the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ do not exist.